# Tkinter How to add a version of a tag to each line in a Text Widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a list in a Text widget, where the user can click on an element in the list and the click event will pull just the element they clicked from the list to pass it to another function.

Unfortunately, when creating the list I seem to be only creating one full tag for the whole list, instead of creating an instance of the tag for each element in the list. I'm not sure how to fix this, any help would be appreciated.

Also, the lambda click event seems to be throwing an error on initiate, but otherwise works fine and doesn't throw the error again. Not sure what is causing it.

My code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
username = "elll321"
offlineUsers = ["sata660", "test400"]
mainFrame = tk.Frame(root)
mainFrame.pack()

viewText = tk.Text(mainFrame, height=20, width=50, bg="white", fg="black")
viewText.grid(row=0)
viewText.insert(tk.END, "People list \n")

viewText.tag_config("offline", foreground="red")
viewText.tag_bind("offline", "<Button-1>", lambda event: userClicked(event, username))

#Loop through all the online users and add them to the text box
for user in offlineUsers:
    viewText.insert(tk.END, user + " \n", "offline")

def userClicked(event, username):
    # get the index of the mouse click
    index = event.widget.index("@%s,%s" % (event.x, event.y))

    offline_tag_indices = list(event.widget.tag_ranges("offline"))

    # iterate them pairwise (start and end index)
    for start, end in zip(offline_tag_indices[0::2], offline_tag_indices[1::2]):
        # check if the tag matches the mouse click index
        if event.widget.compare(start, '<=', index) and event.widget.compare(index, '<', end):
            # return string between tag start and end
            clickedFound = event.widget.get(start, end)

    print(clickedFound)

root.mainloop()
```

The lambda error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\Elisha Lloyd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "D:\Users\Elisha Lloyd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 1254, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'e'
```

---

**Answer for those who may need it:**

stovfl's comment and the linked related post helped find this answer

```
def userClicked(self, event, username, parent):
        index = self.viewText.index("@%s,%s" % (event.x, event.y))
        line, char = index.split(".")
        print("you clicked line %s" % line)

        start, end = line + '.0', line + '.end'

        result=self.viewText.get(start, end)
        print(result)
```

Comment: Use `start, end = line + '.0', line + '.end'`, see [reply.it](https://repl.it/languages/tkinter). Read up on [The Tkinter Text Widget - Indexes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm)

Comment: I'm not getting an error from the lambda.

Comment: @TheMaker Ah, I think then it might be firing in my overall program for some reason when the frame is initiated, which would explain why it is saying it doesn't have the event information when the client is launched. I'm probably not formatting the lambda correctly

Comment: @6Willows It does look like that.

Comment: @stovfl In reference to the start, end comment, where would this be? When I'm inserting the text or when I'm retrieving the tag details to compare it?

Comment: ***start, end ... where would this be?***:  It's defined from the `line` you have clicked with constant arguments for char pos.

Comment: @stovfl After trying to implement one of the answers to your suggested post and then combining that with the start, end line you mentioned, I have got it working. Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to implement? Are you just wanting to detect whether the clicked-on line has the tag "offline" on it?

Comment: @Bryan ***detect whether the clicked-on line has the tag "offline" on it?***: Do you have a short example about this?

Comment: @stovfl: sure, an example is easy, but this question is closed.